# How to get text from python output

Tags: python, variables, soap

Im new in python, and write a script that do soap request to server and give me session id.

```
import requests
import re

endpoint = "http://192.168.66.2:10101/IntegrationService/IntegrationService.asmx?wsdl"

body1="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <OpenSession xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
      <domain>SYSTEM</domain>
      <userName>user</userName>
      <password>pass</password>
    </OpenSession>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""
body1 = body1.encode('utf-8')
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body1))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body1, verify=False)

print(response.content)

SESID = re.search(pattern, SessionID)
print (SESID)
```

output

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><OpenSessionResponse xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService"><OpenSessionResult><Result>0</Result><Value><SessionID>d623e923-1aac-4d59-9754-ab279c191860</SessionID><RootOrgUnitID>f7c724d2-7e24-4257-8271-87caca6909f9</RootOrgUnitID><RootTerritoryID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</RootTerritoryID></Value></OpenSessionResult></OpenSessionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
```

How to get `<SessionID>d623e923-1aac-4d59-9754-ab279c191860</SessionID>` and add it to variable SESID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you store the the output in a variable, you need to convert it from bytes to string using the UTF-8 encoding format.

Then you can slice your way through that string to obtain the SessionID as you wish!

[image: Here's how]

```
x=b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><OpenSessionResponse xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService"><OpenSessionResult><Result>0</Result><Value><SessionID>d623e923-1aac-4d59-9754-ab279c191860</SessionID><RootOrgUnitID>f7c724d2-7e24-4257-8271-87caca6909f9</RootOrgUnitID><RootTerritoryID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</RootTerritoryID></Value></OpenSessionResult></OpenSessionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'

x=str(x,"UTF-8")

# 12 here is equivalent to len("</SessionID>") which I prefer you'd use
# because you would be able to extract anything else by just replacing the keyword

sid=x[ x.index("<SessionID>") : x.index("</SessionID>")+12 ]

print(sid)
```

This will give you the following output

```
'<SessionID>d623e923-1aac-4d59-9754-ab279c191860</SessionID>'
```

Comment: How can i get only d623e923-1aac-4d59-9754-ab279c191860?

Comment: Oh, i do it by myself "sid=x[ x.index("<SessionID>")+12 : x.index("</SessionID>") ]"